# Golang create go routines in batches

Tags: for-loop, go, google-cloud-pubsub, goroutine

I have a list of say 100 thousand records fetched from db, and need to loop over it and send each record to a published and based on the response status from pub-sub need to update the record status back in db.

For now I have created a channel to save the response of pubsub in that array of channel, but I am not sure will it process all those record and update the status in db.

```
for _, record := range records {
    type pubRes struct {
       RecordId string
       Error  error
    }
    pubChan := make(chan pubRes)

    go func(record Record) {
       // publish documents
       pubSubErr := pubsub.Publish(ctx, topicName, map[string]string{
             "id": record.Id,
          })
       pubChan <- pubRes{
          RecordId: record.Id,
          Error:  pubSubErr,
       }
    }(record)

    // bulk update status of record in db
    var successRecordIds []string
    pubResults := make([]pubRes, len(leads))
    for i := range pubResults {
       pubResults[i] = <-pubChan
       if pubResults[i].Error != nil {
          continue
       }
       successRecordIds = append(successRecordIds, pubResults[i].RecordId)
    }

    if err = BulkUpdateStatus(ctx, successLeadIds, "success"); err != nil {
       return err
    }
}
```

Will all of the record status will be updated based on the response from pubsub and will there be no memory issue due to spawned of so go routines?

Or is there any another way to handle this using some limit or batching?

Comment: Dispatching a separate goroutine for every single record of probably not going to be very efficient. Yes you can use some "limit" (semaphore) or "batching" (worker pool). You need to analyze this with your data and system to know what the best approach may be.

Comment: @JimB can you share some example on the "limit" (semaphore) or "batching" (worker pool) if possible, didn't get the exact idea on it.

Comment: @aakashsingh This is a trivial example of a worker pool.
https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

Here you can limit the number of workers (go routines) and pass the records to their channel, instead of creating a goroutine for each record.